# Microphone/audio problems in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I have installed vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 like month ago.
Everything seems to work fine except that any of the built-in microphone in my laptop or an external headset records audio too low and with a ton of noise. This didn't happen in my previous Manjaro installation.

I have tried to remove the pulseaudio driver and install it again but it didn't work.

My laptop is an Acer Aspire 3. Additional info:

```
λ inxi -Fxz                                                                                                                                  0 (19.379s) < 13:25:38
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Aspire A315-42 v: V1.06 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: PK model: Sleepy_PK v: V1.06 serial: <filter> UEFI: Insyde v: 1.06 date: 09/26/2019 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 25.4 Wh condition: 29.0/37.0 Wh (78%) model: PANASONIC 0x41,0x50,0x31,0x36,0x4D,0x35,0x0013 
           status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen+ rev: 1 
           L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 33537 
           Speed: 1297 MHz min/max: 1400/2100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1284 2: 1260 3: 1221 4: 1222 5: 1304 6: 1223 7: 1222 
           8: 1222 
Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Picasso vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
           bus ID: 05:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: amdgpu resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-42-generic LLVM 10.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI 
           driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 05:00.1 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI 
           driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x v: kernel bus ID: 05:00.5 
           Device-3: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: snd_hda_intel 
           v: kernel bus ID: 05:00.6 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-42-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: r8169 
           v: kernel port: 2000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
           IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Lite-On driver: ath10k_pci v: kernel 
           port: 2000 bus ID: 04:00.0 
           IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.03 TiB used: 52.38 GiB (5.0%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Kingston model: RBUSNS8154P3128GJ1 size: 119.24 GiB 
           ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ04ABF100 size: 931.51 GiB temp: 26 C 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 116.38 GiB used: 33.87 GiB (29.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
           ID-2: /home size: 915.89 GiB used: 18.50 GiB (2.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 40.6 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 40 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 279 Uptime: 19h 22m Memory: 5.81 GiB used: 3.03 GiB (52.2%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: fish v: 3.1.2 inxi: 3.0.38
```

Also, this is the output of `journalctl -p err -b`:

```
ago 17 18:02:56 aspire kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
ago 17 18:02:56 aspire kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
ago 17 18:02:56 aspire kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
ago 17 18:02:56 aspire kernel: snd_pci_acp3x 0000:05:00.5: Invalid ACP audio mode : 2
ago 17 18:02:57 aspire kernel: acp_pdm_mach acp_pdm_mach.0: ASoC: failed to init link acp3x-dmic-capture: -517
ago 17 18:02:57 aspire kernel: acp_pdm_mach acp_pdm_mach.0: snd_soc_register_card(acp) failed: -517
ago 17 18:02:57 aspire systemd-backlight[684]: Failed to get backlight or LED device 'backlight:acpi_video1': No such device
ago 17 18:02:57 aspire systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video1.
ago 17 18:03:22 aspire gdm-password][1617]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
ago 17 18:17:59 aspire pulseaudio[1644]: ALSA woke us up to write new data to the device, but there was actually nothing to write.
ago 17 18:17:59 aspire pulseaudio[1644]: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
ago 17 18:17:59 aspire pulseaudio[1644]: We were woken up with POLLOUT set -- however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail() returned 0 or another value < min_avail.
ago 18 08:24:19 aspire systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
ago 18 08:56:27 aspire pulseaudio[1644]: ALSA woke us up to read new data from the device, but there was actually nothing to read.
ago 18 08:56:27 aspire pulseaudio[1644]: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
ago 18 08:56:27 aspire pulseaudio[1644]: We were woken up with POLLIN set -- however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail() returned 0 or another value < min_avail.
```

I think maybe this is a Ubuntu/Debian problem related, since I have also installed Linux Mint 19 and have trouble with audio too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same soundcard and I had recently many trouble with the sound. I just figured out (literally 5 minutes ago) that the problem was with the driver `snd_rn_pci_acp3x`. I blacklisted it and everything started working well. The system is using now the `snd_hda_intel driver`. It's worth a try, just add:

```
blacklist snd_rn_pci_acp3x
```

at the end of the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file.

Comment: I had no input and output devices detected anymore and this saved my day. Thanks!